# reading parquet file from AWS s3 taking so long compared to downloading the file then reading

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to compare performance between streaming data from S3 to create tf.data.Dataset  Vs. downloading parquet files then creating tf.data.Dataset.

As I'm limited to disk and memory storage streaming data straight from S3 seems more suitable for be however performance difference is too large to ignore.

Method 1: streaming data from S3

```
batch_size = 512
fs = s3fs.s3FileSystem()
def read_pq_file(parquet_paths):
    for parquet_path in parquet_paths:
        pq_file = pd.ParquetDataset(parquet_path, filesystem=fs)
        df = pq_file.read().to_pandas()
        curr_row = 0
        while curr_row < len(df):
            batch_df = df.iloc[curr_row:curr_row+batch_size, :]
            X = batch_df[x_features].astype('float32').values
            y = batch_df[label].astype('float32').values
            curr_row += batch_size
            yield (X, y)

def read_and_preprocess(parquet_path):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: read_pq_file(parquet_path), (tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

Method 2: downloading parquet then reading

```
def read_pq_file(parquet_paths):
    for i, parquet_path in enumerate(parquet_paths):
        # download to local
        local_path = f'{i}th_pq.c000'
        download(local_path)
        pq_file = pd.ParquetDataset(local_path)
        df = pq_file.read().to_pandas()
        curr_row = 0
        while curr_row < len(df):
            batch_df = df.iloc[curr_row:curr_row+batch_size, :]
            X = batch_df[x_features].astype('float32').values
            y = batch_df[label].astype('float32').values
            curr_row += batch_size
            yield (X, y)

def read_and_preprocess(parquet_path):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        lambda: read_pq_file(parquet_path), (tf.float32, tf.float32))
```

Then train as follows:

```
train_gen = input_fn(parquet_file_paths)
valid_gen = input_fn(valid_parquet_file_paths)

model.fit(x=train_gen, validation_data=valid_gen, epochs=10)
```

2nd method is 20x faster.
Having a hard time interpreting the result, is this expected result? Reference would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a known problem with S3FS. The default cache type should now be readahead, but it might be worth experimenting with the block size to see if you get perfomance gains out of it. https://github.com/fsspec/s3fs/issues/677